# C# Check the values of dynamic object properites while debugging

Tags: c#, wcf, expandoobject, dynamicobject

I encountered a WCF service which returns a dynamic object. But in debug mode the properties of dynamic objects were not allowed to visible. How to see dynamic object property values while debugging. Image is attached.

[image]